# Why do I get an a SSL handshake failure with .Net Client to RabbitMQ with Erlang 19.1.1 but do not in 17.4 18.1 and 18.2?

Tags: python, .net, ssl, erlang, rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ 3.6.6 and Erlang 19.1 on a Linux box. I followed the SSL guide (http://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html) and can get Python clients to connect but not the .Net client.

I've tried identical server configurations using Erlang (17.4 18.1 and 18.2) which all work.

**Detail using Erlang 19.1 are below**

**Wireshark Client Request**

```
Certificate, Client Key Exchange, Certificate Verify, Change Cipher Spec, Hello Request, Hello Request
    Secure Sockets Layer
        TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Multiple Handshake Messages
            Content Type: Handshake (22)
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Length: 1278
            Handshake Protocol: Certificate
                Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
                Length: 748
                Certificates Length: 745
                Certificates (745 bytes)
                    Certificate Length: 742
                    Certificate: 308202e2308201caa003020102020102300d06092a864886... (id-at-organizationName=client,id-at-commonName=netclient)
                        signedCertificate
                            version: v3 (2)
                            serialNumber: 2
                            signature (sha256WithRSAEncryption)
                                Algorithm Id: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 (sha256WithRSAEncryption)
                            issuer: rdnSequence (0)
                                rdnSequence: 1 item (id-at-commonName=MyTestCA)
                                    RDNSequence item: 1 item (id-at-commonName=MyTestCA)
                                        RelativeDistinguishedName item (id-at-commonName=MyTestCA)
                                            Id: 2.5.4.3 (id-at-commonName)
                                            DirectoryString: uTF8String (4)
                                                uTF8String: MyTestCA
                            validity
                                notBefore: utcTime (0)
                                    utcTime: 16-12-03 19:56:24 (UTC)
                                notAfter: utcTime (0)
                                    utcTime: 17-12-03 19:56:24 (UTC)
                            subject: rdnSequence (0)
                                rdnSequence: 2 items (id-at-organizationName=client,id-at-commonName=netclient)
                                    RDNSequence item: 1 item (id-at-commonName=netclient)
                                        RelativeDistinguishedName item (id-at-commonName=netclient)
                                            Id: 2.5.4.3 (id-at-commonName)
                                            DirectoryString: uTF8String (4)
                                                uTF8String: netclient
                                    RDNSequence item: 1 item (id-at-organizationName=client)
                                        RelativeDistinguishedName item (id-at-organizationName=client)
                                            Id: 2.5.4.10 (id-at-organizationName)
                                            DirectoryString: uTF8String (4)
                                                uTF8String: client
                            subjectPublicKeyInfo
                                algorithm (rsaEncryption)
                                    Algorithm Id: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 (rsaEncryption)
                                subjectPublicKey: 3082010a0282010100b5007e702f32e3e8e307eb07296cf4...
                                    modulus: 0x00b5007e702f32e3e8e307eb07296cf453581e5fa9c6c831...
                                    publicExponent: 65537
                            extensions: 3 items
                                Extension (id-ce-basicConstraints)
                                    Extension Id: 2.5.29.19 (id-ce-basicConstraints)
                                    BasicConstraintsSyntax [0 length]
                                Extension (id-ce-keyUsage)
                                    Extension Id: 2.5.29.15 (id-ce-keyUsage)
                                    Padding: 7
                                    KeyUsage: 80 (digitalSignature)
                                        1... .... = digitalSignature: True
                                        .0.. .... = contentCommitment: False
                                        ..0. .... = keyEncipherment: False
                                        ...0 .... = dataEncipherment: False
                                        .... 0... = keyAgreement: False
                                        .... .0.. = keyCertSign: False
                                        .... ..0. = cRLSign: False
                                        .... ...0 = encipherOnly: False
                                        0... .... = decipherOnly: False
                                Extension (id-ce-extKeyUsage)
                                    Extension Id: 2.5.29.37 (id-ce-extKeyUsage)
                                    KeyPurposeIDs: 1 item
                                        KeyPurposeId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 (id-kp-clientAuth)
                        algorithmIdentifier (sha256WithRSAEncryption)
                            Algorithm Id: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 (sha256WithRSAEncryption)
                        Padding: 0
                        encrypted: 91d59d73fd4fa59494031acf857a0bc94061715b63f9d14d...
            Handshake Protocol: Client Key Exchange
                Handshake Type: Client Key Exchange (16)
                Length: 258
                RSA Encrypted PreMaster Secret
                    Encrypted PreMaster length: 256
                    Encrypted PreMaster: b6907639fa3c297cbbe91a80ca7394569354ba1c04ca9541...
            Handshake Protocol: Certificate Verify
                Handshake Type: Certificate Verify (15)
                Length: 260
                Signature Hash Algorithm: 0x0201
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature length: 256
                Signature: 98730313f2cf8eaa47e3e574f0e090882735ec69f051374a...
        TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Change Cipher Spec Protocol: Change Cipher Spec
            Content Type: Change Cipher Spec (20)
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Length: 1
            Change Cipher Spec Message
        TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Multiple Handshake Messages
            Content Type: Handshake (22)
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Length: 40
            Handshake Protocol: Hello Request
                Handshake Type: Hello Request (0)
                Length: 0
            Handshake Protocol: Hello Request
                Handshake Type: Hello Request (0)
                Length: 0
```

**Wireshark Server Response**

```
Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Erlang Version 17.4, 18.1 or 18.2. I suspect a bug in Erlang as there is another that had issues:

https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-259, ticket is resolved but there is no confirmation of it being fixed from anyone.

Comment: I ended up just going with Erlang 18.2, but am not happy with this solution.